# Excel VBA - Unique List - Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a type mismatch error when I try to run this code on opening the workbook, the line highlighted by the debugger is the 2nd to last, I've added a comment to the code so you know where.

The line where there is an error is the same as a line of code further up so I'm unsure why I get a type mismatch error following the second loop.

I have tested the two loops separately in their own modules and it works fine. It's when I combine them into 1 module and try to run on opening the workbook that I get the error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set InputRng = Worksheets("AA").Range("C2:AF366")
Set OutRng = Worksheets("Unique Lists").Range("A2")

For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value <> "" Then
        dt(rng.Value) = ""
    End If
Next

OutRng.Range("A1").Resize(dt.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dt.Keys)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set InputRng = Worksheets("CT").Range("C2:AF366")
Set OutRng = Worksheets("Unique Lists").Range("B2")

For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value <> "" Then
        dt(rng.Value) = ""
    End If
Next
'ERROR OCCURS ON THE NEXT LINE
OutRng.Range("A1").Resize(dt.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dt.Keys)

End Sub
```

For info: the code is designed to create 2 unique lists from cell ranges on different worksheets upon opening the workbook.

Comment: Are the values your store into the second dictionary long (more the 255 chars)?

Comment: Nope, they're names of people

Comment: In the most friendly manner - why don't you write `Option Explicit` on top of your code, try to compile it and then post it again? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx

Comment: I would set a break Point there and examine the dictionary. Does it have a Count greater than 1? Can't tell I cant see your data. If you have nothing set for the dictionary - i.e. nothing added this will give this error.

Comment: @Vityata : Did I/we miss an obvious?

Comment: @PaulG has the answer, the second dictionary was empy. Thanks

Comment: @R3uK - I tried to debug and noticed that it is not full, then saw your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you have data in your "CT" worksheet**. If all of your cells inside `Range("C2:AF366")` don't have any values, then `dt.Count` = 0 (since your `Dictionary` is Empty), and this will result with a run-time error.

You already defined and set `OutRng`, in `Set OutRng = Worksheets("Unique Lists").Range("B2")`, so in your error line you can use:

```
OutRng.Resize(dt.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dt.Keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to debug dictionary, when you are not sure what do you have inside- take a look at the last lines:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
    Dim dt As Object
    Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set InputRng = Worksheets("AA").Range("C2:AF366")
    Set OutRng = Worksheets("Unique Lists").Range("A2")

    For Each rng In InputRng
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
            dt(rng.Value) = ""
        End If
    Next

    OutRng.Range("A1").Resize(dt.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dt.keys)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set InputRng = Worksheets("CT").Range("C2:AF366")
    Set OutRng = Worksheets("Unique Lists").Range("B2")

    For Each rng In InputRng
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
            dt(rng.Value) = ""
        End If
    Next

    'ERROR OCCURS ON THE NEXT LINE
    OutRng.Range("A1").Resize(dt.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dt.keys)

    Dim dtKey As Variant

    For Each dtKey In dt.keys
        Debug.Print dtKey
    Next dtKey

End Sub
```

Indeed, your code works quite ok when `dt.Count` is not 0.